# Proof of same integral.

Tags: real-analysis

I need some help with the following proof:

Define $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ as an integrable function

Define $g:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ as a random function

To show: If X={$x \in[a,b]:g(x)\neq f(x)$} is finite then g is integrable and $$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bg(x)dx$$

What I found out so far is the following:
I know that g needs to be limited on [a,b]. Since f is integrable decompositions of [a,b] exist, which I can use for g. To show that g is integrable I need to show that Upper and Lower sum are identical but this is where I struggle since I do not have a explicit function.
I saw another thread on this platform where they used Lebesgue integral but I cannot use it since we didn't have it yet in our lectures.
Can someone give me some ideas on how to proceed with my proof?

Comment: How is the integrability defined in your textbook? There are two major ways to define an integral in the preliminary level analysis: either as a Riemann integral (as the limit of Riemann sums) or as a Darboux integral (as the common value of the upper/lower Darboux integrals).

Comment: Here it gets a little tricky. We first introduced Darboux Sums. But later when we talked about integrals we used the Riemann integral.

Comment: Do you use Riemann integral?

Comment: We use the Riemann integral with Darboux sums.

Comment: Let me address an approach which may be implemented in either versions of the definition: Show that the function $$ h_a(x) := \begin{cases} 1, & x = a; \\ 0, & x \neq a; \end{cases} $$ is integrable. Then show that $g(x)$ is a linear combination of $f$ and $\{h_a : a \in X\}$. Since finite linear combination preserves integrability, we are done.

Comment: Ohh, I see where you are going. Just to clarify:
Supposedly, that I already have shown the integrability of $ h(x) $ .
So then what's left to show is that $g(x)=f(x)+t* h_a(x)$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$
But how do I do that? It sounds trivial to me and yet I am unable to show it.

Comment: And the other question is how do I show that the integrals are the same then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We first prove that if $\varphi_c : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is the function defined, if $c\in[a,b]$, by

$$ \varphi_c(x) = \begin{cases} 1 &\quad [x=c] \\[1ex] 0 &\quad [x\neq c], \end{cases} $$

then $\varphi_c$ is Riemann-integrable, and its integral is zero.

Indeed, let us suppose $a<c<b$. Given $\epsilon >0$, we can assume that it is small enough to have $a<c-\epsilon/2$ and $c+\epsilon/2<b$. Consider the partition $P=(a,c-\epsilon/2,c+\epsilon/2,b)$ of $[a,b]$, and the upper sum of $\varphi_c$ relative to $P$:

$$ U(\varphi_c;P)=0\cdot\Big((c-\epsilon/2)-a\Big)+1\cdot\Big((c+\epsilon/2)-(c-\epsilon/2)\Big)+0\cdot\Big(b-(c+\epsilon/2)\Big)=\epsilon. $$

Since $\varphi_c\geq0$, by the integrability Riemann's criterion, we conclude that $\varphi_c$ is Riemann-integrable, and that

$$\int_a^b \varphi_c=0. $$

[Note that actually every lower sum $L(\varphi_c;P)$ is zero.]

Similarly we proceed if $c=a$ or $c=b$. For example, in the first case we consider the  partition $P=(a=c, a+\epsilon,b)$, etc.

Now we suppose that $g$ is obtained from $f$ altering it only in the points $c_1,c_2.\ldots,c_n$. To prove our theorem it is sufficient to note that

$$ g=f+\sum_{k=1}^n (g(c_k)-f(c_k))\varphi_{c_k} $$

as it is easy to verify (just calculating it at the generic point $x\in[a,b]$), and to use the elementary linearity properties of the integral. These properties say that $g$ is Riemann-integrable, and that we have:

\begin{align}
\int_a^b g &= \int_a^b\big[f+\sum_{k=1}^n(g(c_k)-f(c_k))\varphi_{c_k}\big] = \\[1ex]
&= \int_a^b f \;+\; \sum_{k=1}^n(g(c_k)-f(c_k))\int_a^b\varphi_{c_k} = \int_a^b f.
\end{align}