# integrability of a bounded function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, analysis, riemann-integration

I want to show that

> Let f be bounded on [a,b]. If g is bounded on [a,b] and g(x)=f(x) for all but finitely many points in [a,b], then g is integrable on [a,b] and Then $$\int_a^b f=\int_a^b g$$

I have trouble understaing the meaning of the phrase "for all but finitely many".
Does anyone can give me an answer or a hint?

Comment: You are dealing with Riemann integration presumably. Check that if $h(x)=0$ exact at points $x_1,\ldots,x_N$, where it take values, say $H_1,\ldots,H_n$, then $\int^b_ah=0$

Comment: The phrase "for all but finitely many" means that the set of elements for which the property under discussion fails is a finite set.

Comment: You can see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3674809