# Riemann Integral of finite rational activation function.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification, riemann-integration

## The Problem

Suppose I have the function $f_k: [0,1] \to \{0,1\}$ defined by
$$f_k(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & x \in \{r_1,\dots, r_k\}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
where each $r_i \in \mathbb{Q}$. I want to show that $f_k$ for all $k$ is Riemann Integrable.

## What I tried

For fixed $k \geq 1$, fixed $\epsilon > 0$, and assuming each $r_i$ are in increasing order, I construct the partition
$$P = \left\{0, r_1 - \frac{\epsilon}{4k}, r_1 + \frac{\epsilon}{4k}, \dots, r_k - \frac{\epsilon}{4k}, r_k + \frac{\epsilon}{4k}, 1\right\}$$
The lower sum $L(f_k, P) = 0$ clearly, and it is not hard to see that the upper sum
\begin{align*}
U(f_k, P) &= \sum_{i = 1}^\infty\left[r_i + \frac{\epsilon}{4k} - \left(r_i - \frac{\epsilon}{4k}\right)\right]\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^\infty\frac{\epsilon}{2k}\\
&= \frac{\epsilon}{2}
\end{align*}
Clearly from here we have
$$U(f_k,P) - L(f_k, P) = \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon$$
Which proves that $f_k$ is riemann integrable for all $k \geq 1$.

Could I please check if my working is correct?

### Extra question

I am able to prove that if we take $k\to \infty$ we have $f_k \to f$ pointwise where
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & x\in \mathbb{Q}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
I know this function is not riemann integrable because it is the Dirichlet function, but I'm not exactly sure why this is the case. Could someone please explain this to me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Density of the rationals. No matter what partition you take, there will be a rational number inside every interval, so you have no choice but to set $U(f, P) = 1$. Conversely, density of the irrationals requires $L(f,P) = 0$.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins I see. Is my working for the problem at the start acceptable?

Comment: Yeah, seems fine.

Comment: In the calculation of $U(f_k,P)$ the sums must be $\;\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k\ldots$

Furthermore, $\epsilon$ must be small enough so that the partition intervals do not overlap.
 
For another proof, you can see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3674809.